# Separating text inside quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I was wondering if it's possible to separate strings that are inside quotation marks.

I want to use a [**jQuery Plugin**](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html) which makes tags on an item, however there will be multiple tags, and I won't know all possibilities by users, therefore a many to many relationship in a database wouldn't work, as there are many specialised terms that could be used.

I don't mind using a seperate table, however there could be many duplicates, and I'd rather store it in one string in a table.

So would it be possible to seperate text like this:

```
"Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3"
```

Into an array, and loop these in a PHP `foreach` loop, so I can echo these out?

Comment: Have you an example output your text ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev In the database, the whole string would look like: "Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3", and I would like a way to get each "Tag 1" into an array so I can echo in a foreach loop, so the array would look like (array(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: @PublicDisplayName : Do you mean you want to save all the tag's as `"Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3" "Tag 4"` in a single string and in a single record in your database and then you want to fetch it and you want to be able to fetch each tag in array??

Comment: Why not using php function `explode()` - it is straight forward... http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the CSV parser with custom enclosure and delimiters (e.g. whitespace and double quotes).

```
$string = '"Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3" "Tag 4"';
print_r(str_getcsv($string, ' ', '"'));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tag 1
    [1] => Tag 2
    [2] => Tag 3
    [3] => Tag 4
)
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php
Demo: https://eval.in/574590

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

```
$str = '"Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3"';
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ( $arr as $key => $val ) {
  $arr[$key] = trim($val, '"');
  echo $val . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This does basically the following:

- Convert `$str` into an array using spaces as delimiter (delimiter is removed).
- Pick each element as `$val` and strip the enclosing quotes of.
- Save the trimmed element back to the array (for later use).

Answer (score 0):

Well..Here is exactly how you can do it :

**First Part :** To Fetch the tags and then to be able to save it in Database.

**BY USING YOUR  [jQuery TextExt](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/tags-adding.html) PLUGIN :**

**Note :** As your plugin saves the `tags` in a json array.so in order to save those in your Database first you will need to decode the json array and then you can save it in your Database as :

```
<?php
//Assuming Your Tags JSON Array As
$tags = '["javascript","php","jquery","json","html","css"]';
$tags_array = json_decode($tags);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($tags_array);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => javascript
    [1] => php
    [2] => jquery
    [3] => json
    [4] => html
    [5] => css
)
```

**Second Part :** To be able to fetch the tags from Database and to be able to get those in array.

**FETCHING TAGS FROM DATABASE AND THEN GETTING THEM IN AN ARRAY :**

Note : As you will be getting the tags in a string from Database so as :

```
<?php
//Assuming that you fetched your tags in a an array from your database
//But here I am going forward with a string just
$tags = '"Tag 1" "Tag 2" "Tag 3" "Tag 4"';
echo "<pre>";
print_r(str_getcsv($tags, ' ', '"'));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Tag 1
    [1] => Tag 2
    [2] => Tag 3
    [3] => Tag 4
)
```